# l2tp/pptp + freeradius (accounting information only gets updated on disconnect)

Tags: pptp, l2tp, freeradius, xl2tpd

I have a basic PPTP/L2TP setup that uses a remote freeradius server with mysql. Issue is that when a user gets connected to the vpn and as long as the user stays connected (could be hours), no accounting data is updated (bandwidth usage). Only on disconnect does it update the actual bandwidth usage etc.

I have tried setting Acct-Interim-Interval = 30 in the radreply table but still no luck. Is there something i am missing? Any help is appreciated .. thanks.

Comment: The value MUST NOT be <60.
-->http://freeradius.org/rfc/rfc2869.html#Acct-Interim-Interval

Answer (score 1):

add
"ATTRIBUTE       Acct-Interim-Interval   85      integer"
to /etc/radiusclient/dictionary

and return Acct-Interim-Interval in /etc/raddb/users or radreply sql table or others ways you like.

here is the solution:
http://lists.freeradius.org/pipermail/freeradius-users/2007-March/016817.html